# Cloudera Manager : Failed to start service YARN (MR2 Included) , Failed to start Resource manager

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, cloudera-manager, resourcemanager

> Error starting ResourceManager
>   java.lang.NullPointerException
>     at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parseFrom(AbstractParser.java:188)
>     at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parseFrom(AbstractParser.java:193)
>     at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parseFrom(AbstractParser.java:49)
>     at >org.apache.hadoop.yarn.proto.YarnServerResourceManagerRecoveryProtos$ApplicationA>ttemptStateDataProto.parseFrom(YarnServerResourceManagerRecoveryProtos.java:2470)
>   Failed to load/recover state
>   java.lang.NullPointerException
>     at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parseFrom(AbstractParser.java:188)
>     at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parseFrom(AbstractParser.java:193)
>     at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parseFrom(AbstractParser.java:49)

Comment: Update post with more details

Comment: After starting yarn service in the cloudera manager i am getting the below "Starting 4 roles on service
 Service did not start successfully; not all of the required roles started: only 3/4 roles started. Reasons : Service has only 0 ResourceManager roles running instead of minimum required 1."

"Execute command Start this ResourceManager on role ResourceManager (bigdata-pc1)
 Failed to start role."

"Start a role
 Supervisor returned FATAL. Please check the role log file, stderr, or stdout."

Comment: plz update logs from log file

Comment: In the role Log file i am getting the below error message : 
Log Level: ERROR 
SOURCE:org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceManager
Log MEssage:
Failed to load/recover state
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parseFrom(AbstractParser.java:188)
 at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parseFrom(AbstractParser.java:193)
 at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parseFrom(AbstractParser.java:49)

Comment: at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.proto.YarnServerResourceManagerRecoveryProtos$ApplicationAttemptStateDataProto.parseFrom(YarnServerResourceManagerRecoveryProtos.java:2470)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.recovery.ZKRMStateStore.loadApplicationAttemptState(ZKRMStateStore.java:608)
 at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.recovery.ZKRMStateStore.loadRMAppState(ZKRMStateStore.java:591)
 at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.recovery.ZKRMStateStore.loadState(ZKRMStateStore.java:470)

Comment: at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceManager$RMActiveServices.serviceStart(ResourceManager.java:592)
 at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.start(AbstractService.java:193)
 at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceManager.startActiveServices(ResourceManager.java:1021)
 at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceManager$1.run(ResourceManager.java:1062)at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceManager$1.run(ResourceManager.java:1058)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)

Comment: Log Level:FATAL
SOURCE: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceManager
Log Message : Error starting ResourceManager
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parseFrom(AbstractParser.java:188)
 at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parseFrom(AbstractParser.java:193)
 at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parseFrom(AbstractParser.java:49) and same as above error exception details

Answer (score 0):

Did you configure the following in yarn-site.xml ?

yarn.resourcemanager.hostname
yarn.resourcemanager.address